# Create a video file from PGM files

Tags: video, images, python, encoding

Is it possible to create a video file (playable in VLC) from a collection of pgm files. I would like to do this in Python.

Comment: I assume you're referring to portable gray map files. Are you trying to make a slide show or is each image to be a frame in an animation?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I've found to combine images into a movie is to use ffmpeg.  Here's a page on how to do that:  http://electron.mit.edu/~gsteele/ffmpeg/

There's a pyffmpeg project, I don't know if it supports this kind of frame sticking-together, but here's the URL:  http://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/